# Prevent <img> collapse

Tags: jquery, css, html, image

I'm trying to refresh an image by first removing and then adding back its `src` attribute with jQuery, but, unfortunately, this causes it to collapse and shift the elements below it up and down again after I reset it, which is quite annoying. How could I avoid this behavior?

Relevant HTML:

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Result</figcaption>
    <img title="Result" id="result" src="http://example.com/image.bmp">
</figure>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.gallery figure {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.gallery img {
    min-width: 160px;
    width: 65%;
}
```

(the `<figure>` element is included in a `<section>` element which has class="gallery")

Comment: I would add an image then remove the old image instead of just changing the src. change the whole tag.

Comment: @EricRobinson So, I should create a new `img` element in jQuery? That sounds promising. How can I replace an element using jQuery? Could you please provide some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
var res = $("#result");
res.attr("height", res.height()); //fix the image's height
res.attr("width", res.width()); //fix the image's width
var prev = res.attr("src"); //cache the image's src
res.attr("src", ""); //remove src
res.attr("src", prev); //reset src to refresh image
```

If anything looks vague/understandable I'd be glad to explain it.

**Edit:** another method is to wrap your image with a `div` and make sure that the `div` has a fixed height/width. Let's suppose your HTML looks like:

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>Result</figcaption>
    <div id = "wrapper">
        <img title="Result" id="result" src="http://example.com/image.bmp">
    </div>
</figure>
```

JavaScript:

```
var wrap = $("#wrapper");
wrap.css({"height": wrap.height(), "width": wrap.width()}); //fix height and width
var res = $("#result");
var prev = res.attr("src"); //cache the image's src
res.attr("src", ""); //remove src
res.attr("src", prev); //reset src to refresh image
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: This looks like it should work, and I see in Firebug that it does the right thing, but, for some reason, it does not change the behavior. At least, not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `width` and `height` attributes to the image tag.

Something like:

```
<img title="Result" id="result" src="http://example.com/image.bmp" width="250" height="120">
```

That is of course only possible if you know the exact sizes.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do the trick properly. Please see the comment I left for @Samuel...

Answer (score 0):

You can put `width` and `height` attributes on the image so that it maintains its size even if no image is in the element.

Like so:

```
<img src="" width="100" height="200"/>
```

If the dimensions of the images changes, I would leave off the `width` and `height` attributes in the HTML. Instead, when you go to change the `src` attribute in jQuery, first add width and height attributes to the img tag for the size of the image so that the element will maintain its size. Then when the next image is loaded, remove those attributes so the new image is displayed at it's full size.

Comment: Thanks! But I will also need to rescale it. Right now, it has `width: 65%;` in CSS, and it looks like this also makes the height 65%. If I hardcode `height="200"` in the `img` tag, then it makes the image much taller. If I also explicitly specify `height: 65%;` in the CSS, then it behaves just like before...